# Some git commands are slow on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, powershell, performance, cmd

`git status`, `git branch` and `git log` for example are running slow when I issue the commands from a regular privilege powershell.

However, if I run the powershell prompt with admin privileges and I run the above commands, they execute quickly without any issues.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the Windows default?  Are you using any sort of monitoring or EDR software?

Comment: Windows Defender, I have excluded git.exe but to no avail. Also Windows firewall is enabled. @bk2204

Answer (score 2):

Adding git.exe as a process exclusion didn't work for me, but adding **C:\Program Files\Git\*** (also as a process exclusion) solved my issues.

After that, git pull and fetch went from 100 secs to 3 secs in Git Bash, PS and SourceTree.

Comment: Just some extra context:

I never noticed this issue until after installing oh-my-posh and waiting ~15s after each command for my prompt to reappear.  What's most odd is that this only happens on repos that I had done a local windows file copy on.

The original cloned directory would respond < 15ms, but any copies of the cloned directory would take >15s to do a simple `git status`.  

However, creating a Windows Defender exclusion for Git's entire directory also solved this issue.  And it appears the original cloned directory is responding even faster <5ms.